# If $ f$ is a group homomorphism is the inverse image $f^{-1}$ also a group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Given $f:G\rightarrow G'$ a group homomorphism, i need to show if the inverse image $f^{-1}$ is also one or not. Given $a, b \in f(G)$ it is to be shown that $f^{-1}(ab)=f^{-1}(a)f^{-1}(b)$. Let $x,y, k\in G, s\in G'$ such that $f(x)=a, f(y)=b, f(k)=s=ab.$ It follows: $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)=ab.$ Given that $f$ must not be injective, one can at most write $x\in f^{-1}(a),\ y\in f^{-1}(b),\ k\in f^{-1}(s)=f^{-1}(ab).$ It remains to be shown that $xy=k.$ The main difficulty resides in the fact that $f^{-1}(a)$ may have many values.

Can somebody give me a hint how to go further or show an other way of proving or disproving that $f^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the inverse of $f$ (where $f$ is an isomorphism), or the inverse image as you stated? The inverse image only takes sets as arguments.

Comment: $f$ needs to be a group *isomorphism*.

Comment: Sorry. f is not necessarily an isomorphism.

Comment: By $f^{-1}$ is meant the inverse Image of $f$ and not the inverse map, which might not be defined if $f$ is not an isomorphism. $f^{-1}$ is only defined on $f(G).$

Comment: No. I didn't mean that. $f^{-1}$ as an inverse image is always defined once $f$ is defined, whereas the inverse map, $f^{-1}$ is only defined if $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @user249018 You asked if $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism. Homomorphisms are **maps**; the inverse image of $f$ is just a **set of elements**. So you're mixing two notions of $f^{-1}$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes sense only when $f^{-1}$ is a function from $G'$ to $G$. Otherwise, it's meaningless  (a homomorphism is a function, not a relation). In case that $f^{-1}$ exists, i.e. $f$ is invertible, you can reason as follows:

If $f$ is invertible, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ can be written as $ab=f^{-1}(f(a)f(b))$. Now set $f(a)=k$ and $f(b)=l$ to see that:

$$f^{-1}(k)f^{-1}(l)=ab=f^{-1}(kl)$$

Therefore, $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism too.

Comment: The inverse image $f^{-1}$ is defined on the range of $f$. Unfortunately there is one Symbol for both, the inverse map and the inverse Image. The latter one is of course not a function but it is defined.

Comment: @user249018: You missed what I wrote in the parenthesis, I guess. A homomorphism has to be a function, not a relation. It has to be a **function**.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't even a function in general. Take the homomorphsim that sends everything to $0$. $f^{-1}$ is not even a function then.

If you are talking about isomorphisms, the answer is yes and you can prove it this way:

$$f^{-1}(f(a)f(b))=f^{-1}(f(ab))=ab=f^{-1}(f(a))f^{-1}(f(b))$$

If you prefer you can take $c$ and $d$ at the beginning, but since an isomorphism is bijective you can call them $f(a)$ and $f(b)$

Answer (score 0):

> The main difficulty resides in the fact that $f^{-1}(a)$ may have many values.

I think it may be worth considering a specific example of a non-injective homomorphism - say, the quotient map $p:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ sending $z$ to $z$ mod $2$. It's a good exercise to show that there is **no** homomorphism whatsoever (well, except the trivial one) going the other way, that is, from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

It's also worth noting that there is a second main difficulty that you've missed: if $f$ is not *sur*jective, then $f^{-1}(a)$ may have no values at all! We can get a simple example of both these problems happening at the same time: consider the map $q:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$, given by $$q(x)=(x\mbox{ mod }2, 0).$$ As before there is no (nontrivial) homomorphism whatsoever going the other way, and now in addition e.g. $q^{-1}(1, 1)$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks. $f$ must not be surjective. The inverse Image is defined on the range of $f$. Maybe we have a problem of terminology.

Comment: We don't. You do.

Comment: Let $H'<G'$. Then $f^{-1}(H')<G.$ $f^{-1}$ is called the inverse image. This has nothing to do with the inverse map of $f$, which may not exist. How you will call $f^{-1}$ understood in the above sense it doesn't matter.